# jquery class action not called, if set div data got from a POST

Tags: jquery, class, http-post

I'm posting and get data back to set to a text_div:

```
<div id="text_div">
    {{file.text|safe}}
</div>

$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(data){
        $("#text_div").html(data);
    }
});
```

the text_div has paragraphs like below:

```
<p>xxx <a title="FOO" class="bar" href="#">foo</a> xxx xxx. </p>
```

the back data can be to html, but links action can not be called.

```
$("a.bar").click(function(){
    alert('xxx');
});
```

the weired thing is if i set a stack paragraph with the link pattern, class action can be called. i check element by chrome tool, the static paragraph is same with data got from POST request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("a.bar").click(function(){
    alert('xxx');
});
```

Won't work because you're inserting it dynamically. You'll need to bind the click event using the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function like:

```
$("#text_div").on('click', 'a.bar', function(){
    alert('xxx');
});
```

Comment: it works! but why $("a.bar").on('click', function(){...} not work?

Comment: Because with `.on()` you need to bind to an element that exists when the DOM is loaded. From the docs: _Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on(). To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page._